# Storing LatLonType in solr : how to insert them via solrj

Tags: solr, geospatial, solrj

I am going to index a lot of document using GeoSpatial from solr3.1. I can't find a way to add document with solrj passing latitude and longitude. Querying seems to be working.

How can I insert on a LatLonType from solrj ?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Ok problem solved, it wasn't working because of dataset (invalid lat/lon) and String with lat,lon is working on solrj too.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

I'm still getting errors when I'm adding location using solrj with following code.

    StringBuffer location = new StringBuffer();
    location=location.append(rs.getDouble("LATITUDE")).append(",").append(rs.getDouble("LONGITUDE"));

    doc.addField("location", location); // 55.942166056276800,-3.269321178499250

Answer (score 1):

**doc.addField("latlon", "19.2579,72.9862");**